# R apply function to nested list elements using "[["

Tags: r, list, nested, subset

Given a nested list of numeric vectors like
`l = list( a = list(1:2, 3:5), b = list(6:10, 11:16))`
If I want to apply a function, say `length`, of the "index 1 / first" numeric vectors I can do it using the subset function `[[`:

```
> sapply(lapply(l, "[[", 1), length)
a b 
2 5
```

I cant figure how to supply arbitrary indeces to `[[` in order to get length of (in this example) both vectors in every sub-list (a naive try : `sapply(lapply(l, "[[", 1:2), length)`).

Comment: About the operators `[[` vs `[`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1169456/5325862

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[[` can only subset a single one.  Instead, we need `[` for more than 1 and then use `lengths`

```
sapply(lapply(l, "[", 1:2), lengths)
#     a b
#[1,] 2 5
#[2,] 3 6
```

Comment: Keen to realize that I never did hear or use `lengths`.

Answer (score 1):

Not using base, but `purrr` is a great package for lists.

```
library(purrr)

map_dfc(l, ~lengths(.[1:2]))
```

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
      a     b
  <int> <int>
1     2     5
2     3     6
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the code below can help...

```
> sapply(l, function(x) sapply(x, length))
     a b
[1,] 2 5
[2,] 3 6
```